# @Focus called multiple times - Eclipse e4

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp, rcp, e4

I have two parts that are inside a Part Stack.

- `Part1` - Top of the stack
- `Part2` - Bottom of the stack

I've added this code to both of the Parts.

```
@Focus
private void onFocus() {
    System.out.println("On focus called: " + this);
}
```

I've noticed some strange behavior with this.

**Listening to focus on both parts**

1. Click `Part2` tab - `onFocus` called once for `Part2`
2. Click `Part1` tab - `onFocus` called once for `Part1`
3. Click `Part2` tab twice - `onFocus` called twice for `Part2`
4. Click `Part1` tab once - `onFocus` called twice for `Part1`

It seems to be that clicking twice on a tab makes other parts get focused twice.

**Listening to focus on the bottom part only**

1. Click `Part2` tab - `onFocus` called three times for `Part2`
2. Click `Part1` tab - Nothing (As expected as no `onFocus` method added)
3. Click `Part2` tab - `onFocus` called three times for `Part2`

With each of these cases they can vary sometimes. I've had it that `onFocus` isn't called, is called once, twice or three times. I've been trying to find a pattern in this. There is definitely a difference between listening to focus on one part in a stack then two from what I've seen.

Let me know if more information is required.

What could be causing this?

Comment: Please create a ticket for Eclipse Platform UI https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=Platform&component=UI

Comment: I've created a ticket. https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=549654